# Interior-Exterior and Boundary points of a set

Tags: real-analysis

I recently started studying Real Analysis and i'm having a hard time solving this question:

### Let A⊆R be defined by, A={x∈Q : 0 < x  < sqrt(3)}U[2,4]. Find interior, exterior, boundary  and is A closed.

My thoughts:

---

For A's closeness,  x=(o,sqrt(3)) is a open set in R and [2,4] is a closed set in R, combining them not gives us a closed set.

For A's interior my notes says the union of  all open sets  which are contained in A. So it will be (0,sqrt(3)).

For A's exterior, my solution is *extA=(-∞,0]U[sqrt(3),2)U(4,∞)*

I have no idea for boundary of A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interior of $A$ is $(2,4)$, since the elements $a$ of that interval are the only elements of $A$ for which there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\subset A$; just take $\varepsilon=\min\{a-2,4-a\}$.

The exterior of $A$ is $(-\infty,0)\cup\left(\sqrt3,2\right)\cup(4,\infty)$ for a similar reason. And, since the exterior of $A$ is not $A^\complement$, $A$ is not closed.

The closure of $A$ is $\left[0,\sqrt3\right]\cup[2,4]$. Therefore,$$\partial A=\overline A\setminus\mathring A=\left[0,\sqrt3\right]\cup\{2,4\}.$$

Comment: Thanks  for  replying. I don't understand some points.  I found extA=(-∞,0]U[sqrt(3),2)U(4,∞). Why we don't contain 0 and sqrt(3) and write as [ if they are not contained in the main set. And also why it is written as [0,sqrt(3)] in the closure part when it is not containing the points in A?

Comment: The set $\operatorname{ext}A$ could not possibly be that, since the exterior of a set is always an open set. Concerning the closure, it has to be a closed that. If I had written $\left(0,\sqrt3\right)$, that would no happen.